# Transactional Replication Synchronization taking too long to respond

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, enterprise-edition

I successfully generated the snapshot, but subscription is not working correctly. Either the synchronization takes too long to respond or it simply displays the text shown in below attached screenshot.

Here is the successful snapshot generation:

[image: Snapshot generated]

[image: Screenshot for the synchronization status]

It is only retrying and not giving the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following things please:

- Snapshot Agent shows as completed successfully and it has generated its files
- Log reader agent is running and delivering

Right click on each service -> view details - that will help you get more info.
[image: Agents status]

To add to the comments, check the subscription details:
[image: subscription details]
Go to each tab and see if there's any error. If all is good, they should all show green, running, with an action list of delivering transactions.

Comment: As the snapshot was generated successfully so it says completed but the subscription end is not working

Comment: Is the log reader running correctly? Does it say it's delivering commands?

Comment: Yes, i got stuck at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-2017#view-the-synchronization-status-of-the-subscription (View the synchronization status of the subscription)

Comment: See the updated answer pls. How do the 3 tabs look at your end? Any messages/errors showing there?

Comment: Please see the updated question as it shows the successful generation of snapshots and replication monitor also shows no error

Comment: That's only for the snapshot agent part. It correctly generated the snapshot, that's good, but only the 1st step. After that it needs to deliver all this data to the distribution db and after that to the subscriber. So check the subscription details for more info.

Comment: The distribution is on the same server and the View Synchronization Status Dialogue Box on the local subscription says "Agent 'DESKTOP------' is retrying after an error. 5 retries attempted.

Comment: Well then, you found your sore spot :). Dig further in the logs, move past that dialog box, go into Replication Monitor on the actual subscription and see where's the problem. That dialog box is useless now.

Comment: Yeah got it there was an issue with the user account sign in and password change. :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Thanks on this site are send via those up/down arrows (up-votes for useful ones, down-votes for bad ones) and/or Mark as answer :-).